# HTML form second button wont search my database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database set up called customer. I also have a form that allows me to enter data into that database when submit, which is working fine.

However I also want to be able to search the database on the same page.  I added a search field and button, and tried to use an if statement to determine which button was pressed.

The second button for searching the database doesn't seem to be doing anything when pressed, it doesn't seem to even enter the else if statement and I can't see why.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
require("header.php");
connect('final');//connect to DB
header ("location:/xampp/newCustomer.php");
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

//do stuff for submit button here which works fine
}


else if (isset($_POST['btnSearch'])){

echo 'searching'; // test if button is working

$query = $_POST['searching']; 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM customer WHERE 'First_Name' LIKE '$query'") ;


    if($data === FALSE) {
           $error = 'Query error:'.mysql_error();
              echo $error;
                         }
                 else
                        {

                              $test = array();
                              $colNames = array();
                              while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) 
                                                    {
                                                       $test[] = $results;
                                                     }

     $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data);
        if ($anymatches != 0) 
                               {
                              $colNames = array_keys(reset($test));

                                }

if ($anymatches == 0) 
    { 
    echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
    } 

} 
}




}     
?>
```

With my form setup like this:

```
<form name="add"  action="newCustomer.php"  method="post">
 <label><span></span> <input type="text" name="query" palceholder="Type to Search"         id="seaching"/></label>
 <br />
 <label><span>Name</span> <input type="text" name="addFname" /></label>


  <button type="button" name="btnSearch" value="Search"  id="btnSearch"   onclick="this.form.action">Search</button></label>

 <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="true" />
 <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="true" />
 <button type="submit" name="add" value="add" id="btnSub" >Add</button></label>


 </form>
    </html>
```

Comment: why are there two searching inputs? And if the query is the value of searching, why are they hidden?

Comment: and the onclick won't submit the form...and you may use 2 forms ...and there are actually many things that could go wrong including the first remark here above

Comment: header ("location:/xampp/newCustomer.php"); should be in  if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

//do stuff for submit button here which works fine 
}

and change input type from Button to Submit for Search

Comment: Note: Please watch out for SQL Injection: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 1):

you use  `type="button"`, that gives it a button structure but a button dont sumbit a form only a submit does that.

```
<form name="add"  action="newCustomer.php"  method="post">
 <label><span></span> <input type="text" name="query" palceholder="Type to Search"         id="seaching"/></label>
 <br />
 <label><span>Name</span> <input type="text" name="addFname" /></label>


      <button type="button" name="btnSearch" value="Search"  id="btnSearch"   onclick="this.form.action">Search</button></label>

     <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="true" />
     <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="true" />
     <button type="submit" name="add" value="add" id="btnSub" >Add</button></label>


     </form>
        </html>
```

Comment: Even if I change it to submit it won't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<form action="NewCustomer.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="add" value="add"></td>
    </tr>
</form>
<form action="NewCustomer.php" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td>Search: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="search"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="search" value="search"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    echo "add";

}

if (isset($_POST['search'])){
    echo "search"; 
}
?>
```

I think this is what you need :)